DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
this is code i should do and then it should error i dont know what to do
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download ("stopwords")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

and then this should up

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

